# Unhide Next Row Using VBA - Based on table not row

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a command button to unhide extra rows. I have it set so that each time you click the button it unhides the next row. I have 5 of these in the worksheet.

Is it possible change my VBA so that instead of telling it to start at row 17 I can tell it to start at the first row in the table named "Time Labor"?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim r As Long

r = 17
Do Until Rows(r).Hidden = True Or r > 32
    r = r + 1
Loop
If r <= 32 Then Rows(r).Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: "I have 5 of these in the worksheet" - 5 buttons, or five tables?  I think we might need a little more information or a screenshot here.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for the comment. I have five tables and each one has a command button next to it to unhide a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a listobject/table named "Time Labor" then its first row could be found like this:

```
r = ListObjects("Time Labor").ListRows(1).Range.Row
```